# custom animation for flutter tab bar navigation animation

Tags: flutter

How to add custom animation to flutter tabbar and tabbar view i want to add custom navigation animation to the code that is attached below when i attach the tab bar controller i only get the option of animate to certain value i don't want that i want to change the animation completely e.g when i drag or click the tabbar it slides in from that direction what if i want fade in transition or any other animation..

```
class TabsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsPageState createState() => _TabsPageState();
}

class _TabsPageState extends State<TabsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _tabController.index = index;
              });
            },
            controller: _tabController,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                text: 'Hello',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                text: 'World',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            HomePage(),
            Favorites(),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            _tabController.animateTo(1,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 5), curve: Curves.easeIn);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```